# Return wrong URL in Django

Tags: python, html, django

When I click link to another page from 'localhost:8000/product_all/all', it's error: "Page Not Found"
(Note: 'all' is parameter)

It return url 'localhost:8000/product_all/all/useraccount'.

But it should be 'localhost:8000/useraccount'.

If I change page in another page that not be 'product_all/all' page, it's normally. (e.g. from 'add_product' to 'useraccount')

my context

```
menu_list = PagesMenu.objects.all()
dropdown_list = DropdownMenu.objects.select_related('head_dropdown').all()
context = {
    'title': 'Ratchapol Optic',
    'menu_list': menu_list,
    'dropdown_list': dropdown_list,
}
```

in polls/views.py

```
if type == 'all':
    product_list = Product.objects.all()
else:
    product_list = Product.objects.filter(category=type)
pd = {
    'product_list': product_list,
    }
pd.update(context)
return render(request, 'polls/product_all.html', pd)
```

in polls/urls.py

```
path('product_all/<type>/', views.product_all, name='product_all'),
path('useraccount', views.useraccount, name='useraccount'),
```

Note 2: My context is navbar. If I click link on page but not in navbar, it can change page.

Comment: Try to access `'localhost:8000/product_all/all/` with  `/` at the end. Anyway it's wrong API approach. Usually you should use `localhost:8000/products/` for all and `'localhost:8000/products/{id}/` if you want to use particular product.

Comment: I can access 'localhost:8000/product/product_all/all' normally, but I cannot access another page by click link on navbar, such as 'localhost:8000/useraccount' because when I click on link it will be access 'localhost:8000/product_all/all/useraccount'.

Comment: It's caused by your project structure. Could you provide the information of it?

Comment: What is the definition of `DropdownMenu` and `PagesMenu`? How do you render them?

Comment: PagesMenu :
    class PagesMenu(models.Model):
    page_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    page_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    page_url = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    page_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

Comment: DropdownMenu: class DropdownMenu(models.Model):
    head_dropdown = models.ForeignKey(PagesMenu, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dropdown_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    dropdown_page_url = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    page_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

Answer (score 0):

i think you write wrong url in your template file in django project.

in a link element,you should edit `href="/index"` instead of `href="index"`.

if you want use django url in template,

try `<a href="{% url 'index' %}">test</a>` in your template file.

Comment: It has problem on all page.